# JQueryMobile not styling a Checkbox in Dialog

Tags: jquery-mobile, checkbox, dialog

I am opening a page as a dialog. This dialog does not style the checkbox correctly.

[image]

Tried using checkboxradio("create"); but no joy.

How do I get the checkbox to style correctly in the Dialog box??

Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nirmaljpatel/8xMX2/) with the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the `checkbox` in a div with the proper markup

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
        <legend>Agree to the terms:</legend>
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-1" id="checkbox-1" class="custom" />
        <label for="checkbox-1">I agree</label>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/shanabus/8xMX2/12/

Based on the example in the docs here: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/docs/forms/forms-checkboxes.html

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll have to put the checkbox inside of a form tag in order to get jQuery Mobile to style it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this might be a bug. Adding the `<form>` tag works but you also had create but needed refresh for the `checkboxradio()`:

- http://jsfiddle.net/8xMX2/11/

JS

```
$('#page2').live('pageshow', function(){
    $("input[type='checkbox']").checkboxradio("refresh");
});​
```

HTML

```
<div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Page One</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <a href="#page2" data-role="button" data-rel="dialog">Open as Dialog</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="page2" data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header">
        <a href="#" data-rel="back">Back</a>
        <h1>Page Two</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <form>
            This is a dialog Box. 
            JQM seems to be not styling the below checkbox.<br>

            <input type="checkbox" name="cb1" id="cb1" />
            <label for="cb1">A Checkbox</label>
            <br>
            A button is styled well.<br>

            <a href="#" data-role="button">Just a Button</a>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>​
```